# Why are centaurs only interested in astronomy?

Tags: harry-potter

Hagrid explicitly states in *Harry Potter and The Philosopher's Stone*

> "Ruddy star-gazers. Not interested in anythin' closer'n the moon." 
>  <sub>*Chapter 16: Through the trapdoor*</sub>

Is there a reason why the Centaurs are only interested in astronomy?

Comment: I don't think Hagrid was meaning it literally that they are only interested in astronomy. I think he was more making fun of them for being all mystical and isolated from everybody else.

Comment: I think the centaurs are also interested in lady centaurs.

Answer (score 3):

It's only metaphorical. What he meant is that they aren't interested in anything mundane.

As for astronomy specifically - Firenze also teaches different means of divination in *the Order of the Phoenix*.

I don't have direct citation available, but it was something like

> He taught them about burning herbs and looking for shapes in the smoke. No one saw anything, but Firenze wasn't disappointed. He explained that even centaurs have trouble with divination.